# Interior Brick Wall

Tags: brick, interior

We have a 15x15 Interior wall and would like to use exposed brick, We have stained concrete floor 2x6 walls (This is new construction)
We would like to use real brick or Pavers and split them in half due to the weight and to go further. Any suggestions to install such as Backerboard and Tie-ins?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even 'half bricks' up 15' vertical is going to be a massive amount of weight that may require additional support underneath. In addition, splitting bricks in half is no easy task. You're going to end up paying a whole lot in labor to do that.

Instead, you'd want to use a brick veneer. Which *is* 'real' brick but very thin:

[image]

They go on essentially like you would tiles. The other benefit compared to 'half bricks' is that you won't have to mortar the joints to the same extent to make it look right.